# A formula which eliminates rows based on true/false values (without leaving blank rows)

Tags: excel-formula

Say columns A and B contain numbers. If column C contains either `TRUE` or `FALSE` (based on column A and B values), is there a way to eliminate all rows containing a `TRUE` value (without leaving a bunch of blank rows)? Or simply to duplicate rows A and B for which C is `FALSE`.

For instance, given:

```
    |   A   |   B   |   C
----------------------------
1   |   1   |  10.5 | FALSE
2   |   1   |   15  | FALSE
3   |   2   |  12.2 | FALSE
4   |   2   |  12.4 | TRUE
5   |   3   |  11.5 | FALSE
6   |   3   |   13  | FALSE
7   |   3   |  11.6 | TRUE
8   |   4   |  10.6 | TRUE
9   |   4   |   11  | FALSE
10  |   4   |  11.4 | TRUE
```

I'd like to get :

```
     |   A   |   B   |   C
 ----------------------------
 1   |   1   |  10.5 | FALSE
 2   |   1   |   15  | FALSE
 3   |   2   |  12.2 | FALSE
 4   |   3   |  11.5 | FALSE
 5   |   3   |   13  | FALSE
 6   |   4   |   11  | FALSE
```

or duplication is fine too, as long as there aren't any blank rows, something like:

```
    |   A   |   B   |   C   | D |   E   |   F
------------------------------------------------
1   |   1   |  10.5 | FALSE |   |   1   |  10.5 
2   |   1   |   15  | FALSE |   |   1   |   15  
3   |   2   |  12.2 | FALSE |   |   2   |  12.2 
4   |   2   |  12.4 | TRUE  |   |   2   |  12.2 
5   |   3   |  11.5 | FALSE |   |   3   |  11.5 
6   |   3   |   13  | FALSE |   |   3   |   13  
7   |   3   |  11.6 | TRUE  |   |   4   |   11  
8   |   4   |  10.6 | TRUE  |   |
9   |   4   |   11  | FALSE |   |
10  |   4   |  11.4 | TRUE  |   |
```

Comment: You could use lookups to create another table with what you desire, if you expecting the same table to transform, this cannot be done with formula... You would need to do the task manually or with VBA / Macros

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor How would I use the lookups then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=INDEX(A$1:A$10,MATCH($C$1:$C$10,FALSE,0))`

This assumes that `FALSE` is a proper boolean `TRUE / FALSE` value, you will need to use quotes like `"FALSE"` if it is a string instead.

This should update as dragged across the range (wrap the formula in `=IFERROR(  ,"")` to give blank cells rather than errors.